# Is it possible to convert ArcGIS .mxd to QGIS .qgs without having ArcGIS installed?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, convert, mxd

I was reading **[Converting ArcGIS (*.mxd) file to QGIS (*.qgs) file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/23717/8718)**.

It looks as though this only works with ArcGIS 10.

I would like to do this, but am unable to install things on the computer that has ArcGIS.

Is there a way to import to QGIS without using mxd2qgis (that requires ArcGIS 10)?

Comment: I looked for a solution some time age. Unfortunately, without success.

Answer (score 4):

The MXD format is proprietary to Esri and only readable by products of the ArcGIS Platform (and ArcObjects).

Consequently, I think the most likely way that you will be able to read an MXD without using ArcGIS at some time in the future, is if you submit an **[ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com)** for an Open API to the MXD format to be developed, and that idea attracts a compelling number of votes.

Esri has previously released an **[Open API to the File Geodatabase](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geodatabase/interoperability)** format.