# Importing MXD and/or CAD template into QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mxd, cad

ArcGIS is used very widely in Environmental consultancy and the print/map templates used for reports are usually passed around in an MXD  or CAD file format.  Unfortunately we cannot afford ArcGIS and to be honest I much prefer QGIS.

At the moment we use the CAD file to then create a copy of the print template in the print composer.  However this is a little time consuming and is pretty redundant work considering the MXD and CAD files are already at our disposal.

Is there a way to simply import the print composer template either from a CAD file or MXD?

I've seen the MXD2QGS plugin for ArcGIS discussed in the [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23717/how-to-convert-arcgis-mxd-file-to-qgis-qgs-file), does this also create the print composer template or does it just export the layers?

We could feasibly ask our clients and people we work with to install this and do the conversion, but really I'm looking for a solution on the QGIS side.

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to pursue doing this from an MXD or a CAD file (not both) in this particular question.  I would expect both questions to have already been asked and answered on this site.