# Handling German umlaut while converting ArcGIS file (*.mxd) to QGIS file (*.qgs)

Tags: qgis, convert, mxd

The name of the sole layer in the draft ArcGIS map `myfile.mxd` is `Mächtigkeit` which contains the German umlaut `ä`. I face an error message when using the script `mxd2qgs.py` (downloaded from https://github.com/fitnr/mxd2qgs) although some workarounds are implemented. The script `mxd2qgs_short.py` below is, to my point, the most possible reduction of the original script, still producing the error.

It looks like the error occurs from interaction of the two sections `Section mapcanvas` and `Section legend` with each other. Turning off `Section mapcanvas` makes the error message disappear. I don't manage to trace the interaction of the layer name with `Section mapcanvas`. How should I proceed in `mxd2qgs_short.py` to handle this problem?

Using `doc.toprettyxml()` is suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23717/converting-arcgis-mxd-file-to-qgis-qgs-file).

Script `mxd2qgs_short.py`:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"myfile.mxd")
qgs = 'myfile.qgs'

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
lyrlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(df)
lyr, = lyrlist

doc = Document()
qgis = doc.createElement("qgis")
doc.appendChild(qgis)
legend = doc.createElement("legend")
qgis.appendChild(legend)
unit = doc.createTextNode(df.mapUnits)
units = doc.createElement("units")
units.appendChild(unit)

# Section mapcanvas
mapcanvas = doc.createElement("mapcanvas")
qgis.appendChild(mapcanvas)
mapcanvas.appendChild(units)

# Section legend
legendlayer = doc.createElement("legendlayer")
legendlayer.setAttribute("name",lyr.name.encode('iso-8859-1'))
legend.appendChild(legendlayer)

f = open(qgs,"w")
f.write(doc.toprettyxml())
f.close()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\mxd2qgs_short.py", line 31, in <module>
    f.write(doc.toprettyxml())
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 61, in toprettyxml
    return writer.getvalue()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\StringIO.py", line 271, in getvalue
    self.buf += ''.join(self.buflist)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments of Python's `StringIO.py`'s `getvalue`, it was noted that if the data source for the IO object contained both unicode and 8-bit strings, with any of the latter containing 8-bit but non-ASCII characters (like ä encoded in iso-8859-1), `UnicodeDecodeError`s could result. Since you've found commenting out the `mapcanvas` section avoids error, and the `units` element is a child of that element in your structure, I would check the value of `df.mapUnits`, as that is more data directly out of ArcPy and I suspect that it uses unicode strings universally. While you've encoded the layer name in a format for 8-bit string characters, if `df.mapUnits` is also a unicode string - even if it doesn't contain any non-ASCII characters - the error you're seeing might occur (it did when I attempted to replicate it). To fix it if that is the case, you can encode `df.mapUnits` as well in the same encoding, e.g.:

`unit = doc.createTextNode(df.mapUnits.encode('iso-8859-1'))`

In general, you'll probably want to make sure you apply your choice of output encoding consistently across any strings you're getting from ArcPy (in the code sample that's just `lyr.name` and `df.mapUnits`, but if the broader script contains other string values straight from ArcPy then encode those too).