# Converting symbols from ArcGIS Desktop to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, export, mxd, qgs

How do I export map information display styles from ArcGIS Desktop to QGIS?

I tried exporting MXD to QGS (using mxd2qgs) - but the styles were not saved;Also, when I try to export styles from arcgis to SLD format (using ArcGIS_SLD_Converter) and finally got:

> "Index outside the range."

The index should be a positive number, and its size should not exceed the size of the collection
Parameter name: index
in System.collections.ArrayList.get.item (lnt32 index)
in ArcGis_SLD_Converter.Output_SLD.WriteToSLD()"

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, then I think it should at least be referenced within your question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/23717/115